# encrypting a value within a structure using structfind and structfindvalue

Tags: coldfusion

I have a function which is coming as `structform` to the `cffunction`

the structform is a structure and i tried it use a structfind to find  value and encypt its value

i tried like this

```
<cfset fvalue = structfind(structform,"name")>
<cfset fvalue>
<cfset stuctform = encrypt(structfindvalue(
```

not sure how and how i can fix it

I am not sure the approach i am following is correct or not, any guidance will be appreciated

Comment: I don't quite follow the question... and the code posted doesn't compile. Can you please post a *valid* code snippet AND  a brief explanation of the actual results and how they're different than what you expected ?

Comment: Th code is incomplete because i do not know how should i find a key and its value in a structure and encypt it.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer as to what you're asking for? Provide an example of input data and what you expect to get back out before you encrypt it.

Comment: If you know the value that you want to encrypt, why do you need to find it in your struct? Or did you mean "key" rather than "value"?

Comment: Add what are you trying to accomplish to the question. Just using a function named `encrypt` is meaningless.

Comment: I am trying to find a key in structure and encypt its value

Comment: Then you don't need structFind(). Just use associative array notation to get a key's value: `<cfset theValue = yourStructure["theKeyName"]>`.  Can you please explain what difficulty you are having with using the [encrypt()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html) function?

Comment: @Ageax I think he wanted to use `structFindKey()` to walk up a structure of structures to find the specified key that may not always be in the same place.

Comment: @Shawn - Oh ok, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get TryCF (https://trycf.com) to save, so run this there to see how it works. You'll want to remove the comments and the dumps when you're ready to roll with it. I've included both encryption and decryption of your value, since there's not really much value to encryption if you can't also decrypt. You'll want to save your key somewhere so that you can decrypt it later. I used `generateSecretKey()` to make the encryption key. If you use a different one, you can just pass it in to the function. This uses ColdFusion's `encrypt()` and `decrypt()`, so you can change this if you need something stronger.

```
<cfscript>
    // First we build up a nested struct.
    mystruct = {
        first : {
            second : {
                name  : "notEncrypted" ,
                dob   : "1950-1-1" ,
                other : "stuff"
            }
        }
    } ;

    // This dumps the original struct for verification
    writeDump(var=mystruct,label="originalStruct") ;

    // Now we create our Secret Key for encryption. Store this 
    //somewhere. We'll need it to decrypt.
    mySecretKey = GenerateSecretKey("AES") ;

    // This is our function to encrypt and decrypt our key's value.
    // We pass in our structure, the key we're looking for, the encryption key, and 
    // whether we're encrypting or decrypting. Since both are essentially the same 
    // code, I just included them in the same function
    function xxcryptStuffByKey ( 
        required Struct inStruct, 
        required String theKey, 
        required String theEncKey, 
        required String EorD 
    ) {
        // Where is the key we want in our struct?    
        var whereAmI = structFindKey(arguments.inStruct,arguments.theKey) ;

        // Create the return variable
        var outStruct = {
            // This is the value of the key we're looking for.
            myData : whereAmI[1].value , 
            myKey  : arguments.theEncKey 
        } ;

        // Do we encrypt or decrypt?
        var newData = "" ;
        if (arguments.EorD == "E" ) {  // Encrypt
            newData = encrypt(outStruct.myData, outStruct.myKey, "AES", "Base64") ;
        }
        else if (arguments.EorD == "D") {  // Decrypt
            newData = decrypt(outStruct.myData, outStruct.myKey, "AES", "Base64") ;
        }
        else {  // Oops. Just return our original struct, or throw an error.
            return outStruct;
        }

        "inStruct#whereAmI[1].path#" = newData ; 
        // The " notation on the left lets us update the struct. 
        // NOTE: CF Structures are Pass By Reference = you will be
        // modifying the original struct.

        // We want to see what happened in the function.
        writeDump(var=outStruct,label="InFunction");

        return outStruct ;
    }

    // Encrypt our key value.
    // This will overwrite your original struct. Are you sure?
    xxcryptStuffByKey(myStruct, "name", mySecretKey, "E") ;
    // This gives us ...
    writeDump(var=myStruct,label="EncryptedStruct");

    // Now let's decrypt our encrypted value.
    xxcryptStuffByKey(myStruct, "name", mySecretKey, "D") ;
    // This gives us ...
    writeDump(var=myStruct,label="DecryptedStruct");
</cfscript>
```

Comment: "I can't get TryCF to save" Probably due to [github dropping anonymous Gist creation](https://blog.github.com/2018-02-18-deprecation-notice-removing-anonymous-gist-creation/) which apparently breaks TryCF.

Comment: FWIW, you can create still create a gist under your own account and call it via "id": `https://trycf.com/scratch-pad/gist/7926175` or with a pastebin "id", `https://trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=WWvwuZk2`

Comment: @Ageax May need to do that. I thought it was an issue with firewalls, but I tried it from a different connection and still no joy. I sent a bug message.

Comment: @Ageax Never mind. Just read your first message and now see the problem. :-S

Comment: Yeah.. unfortunate. Maybe they can replace it with Pastebin.